# Can browser (Chrome, Firefox) extensions install additional certificate authorities?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, ssl, google-chrome-extension, man-in-the-middle

Free VPN extensions are available for popular browsers.

Typically, HTTPS traffic should be safe for traversal through these VPNs ... unless the extension can install additional certificate authorities into the browser and perform SSL/TLS man-in-the-middle attacks.

So, can extensions of browsers (specifically interested in Chrome and Firefox) install additional certificate authorities?

Comment: No. They can't, especially not in Chrome. But they don't have to, to be able to seriously compromise your security if malicious.

Comment: @pvg Could you explain further? What other ways can security be compromised?

Comment: An extension doesn't need to mitm you or install certs. It can just look at all the data that passes through your browser. Your adblocker does.